# Controller "SecurityController::loginAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$authenticationUtils" argument

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, symfony-3.4

I am trying to set up a login form since removing the fos user bundle from my project (symfony3.4)

My problem is with the loginAction that it requires AuthenticationUtils but it receives null.

I tried linking it in my services.yml but it will not budge.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here the following files [SecurityController.php, services.yml, routing.tml]

SecurityController.php

```
<?php

 namespace AppBundle\Controller;
 
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
 
 class SecurityController extends Controller
 {
     public function loginAction(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
     {
         // get the login error if there is one
         $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

         // last username entered by the user
         $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

         return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
             'last_username' => $lastUsername,
             'error'         => $error,
         ]);
     }
 }
```

routing.yml

```
login:
  path: /{_locale}/login
  defaults: { _controller: 'AppBundle:Security:login' }
  requirements:
    _locale: "%languages%"
```

services.yml

```
services:      
    AppBundle\Controller\SecurityController:
        class:  'AppBundle\Controller\SecurityController'
        arguments: ['@security.authentication_utils']
```

hopefully anyone has an idea because i have been stuck for a few days now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would use autowiring, this was easier (as you would not need any complex configuration to use services in actions) - but let's see why this currently does not work.

Through your service configuration, you provide arguments for the constructor of `AppBundle\Controller\SecurityController`. That class does not contain any constructor in the current state, so the class does not contain any reference to the `AuthenticationUtils` service.

If you don't want to use autowiring, this would help: add a constructor to your controller class, and Symfony's container will inject the service

```php
class SecurityController extends Controller
 {
     private $authenticationUtils;

     public function __construct(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils) {
         $this->authenticationUtils = $authenticationUtils;
     }

     public function loginAction()
     {
         // get the login error if there is one
         $error = $this-authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

         // last username entered by the user
         $lastUsername = $this-authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

         return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
             'last_username' => $lastUsername,
             'error'         => $error,
         ]);
     }
 }
```